# Barcharts: grouping bars using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-wrap

I want to group these bars by the variable "env".

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Sample, fill = phylum, y = Abundance)) +    
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity") + theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ env) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 13, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), legend.title = element_text(size = 15),  
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black")) + 
  ggtitle("Minion samples: Proteobacteria Phyla") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Acidobacteria"="#3288bd", 
                               "Actinobacteria" = "#99d594",
                               "Candidatus Rokubacteria" = "#74c476",
                               "Chloroflexi"= "#e6f598",
                               "Planctomycetes"="#fee08b",
                               "Proteobacteria" = "#fc8d59",
                               "Verrucomicrobia" = "#a50f15",
                               "Taxa less than 1%" = "#d53e4f"))
```

I get this:

[image]

I would like to have an unique x-axis and get rid of these empty spaces. Is there an other option beside facet_wrap?

Thanks

Comment: Would `facet_wrap( ~ env, scales = "free")` do the job?

Comment: facet_wrap( ~ env, scales = "free_x")

Comment: Actually, is there an alternative option to facet_wrap to avoid different boxes of plots (2 rows and 2 columns)? I would just like have the x-axis on the same line, just one row. Thanks

Comment: Easy:   facet_wrap( ~ env, scales="free_x", nrow = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, indeed using `facet_wrap(~env, scales = "free, nrow =1)` will solve your issue.

Moreover, you might want to have an equal width for the histograms, in this case you can use `facet_grid` and the `space` argument to have something like this:

[image: facet_grid(~env, scales="free", space="free"]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Sample, fill = phylum, y = Abundance)) +    
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(. ~ env, scales = "free", space = "free")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 13, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), legend.title = element_text(size = 15),  
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black")) + 
  ggtitle("Minion samples: Proteobacteria Phyla") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Acidobacteria"="#3288bd", 
                               "Actinobacteria" = "#99d594",
                               "Candidatus Rokubacteria" = "#74c476",
                               "Chloroflexi"= "#e6f598",
                               "Planctomycetes"="#fee08b",
                               "Proteobacteria" = "#fc8d59",
                               "Verrucomicrobia" = "#a50f15",
                               "Taxa less than 1%" = "#d53e4f"))
```

Whereas, `facet_wrap(~ env, scales = "free", nrow = 1)` results in unequal width distribution when free on one row:
[image: facet_wrap(~env, scales ="free", nrow =1)]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Sample, fill = phylum, y = Abundance)) +    
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ env, scales = "free", nrow = 1)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 13, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), legend.title = element_text(size = 15),  
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black")) + 
  ggtitle("Minion samples: Proteobacteria Phyla") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Acidobacteria"="#3288bd", 
                               "Actinobacteria" = "#99d594",
                               "Candidatus Rokubacteria" = "#74c476",
                               "Chloroflexi"= "#e6f598",
                               "Planctomycetes"="#fee08b",
                               "Proteobacteria" = "#fc8d59",
                               "Verrucomicrobia" = "#a50f15",
                               "Taxa less than 1%" = "#d53e4f"))
```

#### Data

---

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(18)
dat = data.frame(
  env = factor(rep(sample(c("Dry", "Fossil", "Wet", "Soil"), size = 25, prob = c(3,2,18,2), replace = T), each=8), levels =c("Dry", "Fossil", "Wet", "Soil")),
  Sample = rep(paste0("Sample_",letters[1:25]), each=8),
  phylum = rep(c("Acidobacteria", "Actinobacteria","Candidatus Rokubacteria","Chloroflexi","Planctomycetes", "Proteobacteria", "Verrucomicrobia","Taxa less than 1%"),times = 25),
  Abundance = runif(200,0,1))
```